# Does SNS retain my data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am evaluating push notification services and cannot use services on the cloud as laws prohibit customer identification data being stored off-premise.

**Question**
Is there any chance data will be stored off-premise if I use AWS-SNS API (not the console) to send push notifications to end user devices via code hosted on-premise(using AWS SDK)? In other words, will SNS retain my data or will it forget it right after it send the notification?

**What have I tried so far?** 
Combed through the documentation as much as I could, but couldn't find anything to be 100% sure.

Would appreciate any pointers on this. TIA.

Comment: I'm not sure what exact meaning the law has for "stored", but the data will exist in memory and possibly persisted to disk *temporarily* on AWS servers until the notification is sent to all subscribers to the topic.

Comment: Thank you @idbehold. I meant if the data will be persisted in a database or a file in AWS servers. Can you please share some reference in AWS documentation that says so?

Answer (score 1):

I would pose this question directly to AWS as it pertains to a legal requirement. I would clarify if the laws you need to comply with are in relation to data at rest or in transit, or both. Additionally if there are any circumstances where it would be ok for one or both of the aforementioned if there was certain security aspects that have been met.

Knowing no real detail about your use case I will say that AWS has a Region specifically for use by the US Government. If your solution is for the US Government then you should be making use of this Region as it ticks off a lot of compliance forms for you well in advance.

You can open a support ticket in the AWS console.

Again if there is a legal requirement for your data I thoroughly recommend that you ask AWS directly so that you may reference their answer in writing in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Even if they didn't store it, how can you prove that to auditors?

Besides, what is the difference between storing something in memory (which they obviously have to do) and storing something on disk?   One is volatile and the other isn't I guess.  But from a compliance point of view, an admin on the box can get both, so who cares if the hardware with your data on it is a stick of RAM or a disk plugged into a SATA port?